# javascript data wont show in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get ajax data from my controller to view. but the javascript code seems doesnt execute well. here's my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function view_data(act){
                  var w = $('#origin').val();
                  var x = $('#destination').val();
                  var y = $('#weight').val();
                  var z = $('#courier').val();

                  if(w == "" && x == "" && y == "" && z == "" ){
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                  }else{
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Cart/getCost",
                      type: "GET",
                      data : {origin: w, destination: x, berat: y, courier: z},
                      success: function (ajaxData){
                          $("#result").html(ajaxData);
                      }
                    });
                  }



              };
          </script>
```

for orgin and destination is came from option select
and for weight and courier from input text.
here's my controller

```
function getCost()
{
    $origin = $this->input->get('origin');
    $destination = $this->input->get('destination');
    $weight = $this->input->get('weight');
    $courier = $this->input->get('courier');

    $data = array('origin' => $origin,
                    'destination' => $destination,
                    'weight' => $weight,
                    'courier' => $courier

    );

    $this->load->view('rajaongkir/getCost', $data);
}}
```

the problem is , data wontt show up in #result on view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your url to this  :

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Cart/getCost",
```

in ajax you have to give full url address . 
please replace load view , to `var_dump` , and in your ajax success part, `console.log(result)` to show what we have in controller . 

 **Second one:** 
another way is to set your view to a variable ( i name it , $Datares) , and add this code after it

```
$this->set_output($Datares);
```

Comment: @SyahrulRomadhon i update my answer . please give me feedback

Comment: the thing is , data that I'm try to get is from view2. cz I use API for get cost shipping. so the controller in this case is use for send data from view1 to view2. so if I replace view to var_dump it would be nothing there

Comment: @SyahrulRomadhon answer is  updated , please set $this->load->view('rajaongkir/getCost', $data); to variable that i explain above .

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function view_data(act){
                  var w = $('#origin').val();
                  var x = $('#destination').val();
                  var y = $('#weight').val();
                  var z = $('#courier').val();

                  if(w == "" && x == "" && y == "" && z == "" ){
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                  }else{
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "Cart/getCost",
                      type: "GET",
                      data : {origin: w, destination: x, berat: y, courier: z},
                      success: function (ajaxData){
                          $("#result").html(ajaxData);
                      }
                    });
                  }
              };
</script>

function getCost()
{
    $origin = $this->input->get('origin');
    $destination = $this->input->get('destination');
    $weight = $this->input->get('weight');
    $courier = $this->input->get('courier');

    $data = array('origin' => $origin,
                    'destination' => $destination,
                    'weight' => $weight,
                    'courier' => $courier

    );

    echo $data;
    exit;
}
```